# How can I rewrite parts of a Location header with nginx?

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to setup a reverse proxy nginx in a docker-compose setup I have. It works fairly well, but I have a problem with a 302 redirect.

The nginx server runs on https://localhost:1253. When I return the redirect within my internal server, nginx will use the internal name (serviceweb) of my docker container in the redirect uri. This is my redirect uri:

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?response_type=code&<...>&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%serviceweb%2Fsignin-google...
```

I'd like to change `serviceweb` to `localhost:1253`.

How can I do this with nginx?

I've tried this simple setup:

```
    location / {
        proxy_pass https://serviceweb;
        proxy_redirect serviceweb localhost:1253;
    }
```

But this does not quite work. The location header still contains the original value. I'm sure I somehow have a problem in the `proxy_redirect` rule , but I'm not sure how. There's a regex based way of doing it according to http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_redirect, and I think my current setup would work with that.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the original value? `proxy_redirect` matches from the start of the string, which is probably `https://serviceweb/`

Comment: You mean the original of the redirect location? That would be the one with accounts.google.com. My host is https://localhost:1253, and the service running in docker is https://serviceweb (internal docker DNS)